# Could not find artifact com.cache:mycache:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in lib

Tags: java, maven

**Added in pom.xml**

```
  <repository>
    <id>lib</id>
    <name>lib</name>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>        
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
   </repository>
```

**added dependecnies**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycache</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added mycache-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in libs folder of root directory but Still not working.

Comment: Why using a libs directory via repository?

Comment: I dont want to use jfrog or any other repository system. Cant a local jar can be included ?

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use a repository manager? Are you in corporate environment or Open Source?

Comment: Its a small project for thirdparty

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment yes or no? It does not matter if it's a thirdparty project? Use the existing infrastructure to simplify your setup and work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

`/libs/com/cache/mycache/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mycache-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

All repositories need to match the standard repository structure.

Comment: Its working with absolute path, can it work with repository ?